# Проблемы с Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

Уже несколько лет использую Ubuntu (Unity) но последним временем начались страшные глюки (после обновления).

Не выходит со сна, просто зависает, падает окружение рабочего стола! Ставится без проблем, до обновления через `sudo apt-get update/upgrade` или `synaptic` работает нормально, но после этого начинаются проблемы, а если поставить скачивать обновление вовремя установки - проблемы начинаются сразу!

Ставил на несколько разных машин (проблемы одинаковые)

1. **Acer** *aspire v3-571g*
2. **Lenovo** *IdeaPad Z510 i5 4200M*

Пространство делю (Ubuntu - единственная ОС на компютере):

- root - 20gb
- home - 70gb
- swap - в 2 раза больше оперативки

Ставил на полностью отформатированный HDD.

*Как быть с этим ?*

**Возможно не у меня одного проблемы такие с Ubuntu 16.04.01 ?** 
 **Стоит ли вернутся к Ubuntu 14.04 ?** 
**Или вообще поменять ОС (*если да, то посоветуйте самое стабильное и надежное*)?**

Результат df -h:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может попробовать другой  линукс?
Скорее всего у Вас проблема с тем, что ставиться какой то пакет, который "мешает". Например, драйвер видео.
Также мне кажется, что 20Гб под корень маловато. нужно ну хотя бы 30 или 40.

Comment: @KoVadim, возможно действительно что-то "мешает", но раньше такого не было! 
Насчёт другого линукса - сомнение между Fedora и Debian!

Comment: Пробуйте дебиан - это как убунта, только консервативное и стабильнее.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо) А разбивка дискового пространства, та что я сделал - подойдет ?

Comment: Берите хотя бы 30 под корень. Кстати, проверьте на Вашей убунте свободное место df -h

Comment: @KoVadim, проверил - результат добавил к вопросу

Comment: @KoVadim, а какую оболочку посоветуете ?

Comment: я пользуюсь xfce, уже очень давно (со времен, как появился gnome3). Ещё мои знакомые используют OpenBox.

Comment: @KoVadim, это чисто из за вкуса или Gnome3  не очень ?

Comment: мне нравиться идеология, которая в xfce и которая была в втором гноме. Поэтому я и использую xfce

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо за совет )

Comment: @KoVadim, Прислушался к вам и поставил Debian 8 (( Все работает отлично, но не знаю как wifi включить! Не могли бы подсказать ?

Answer (score 3):

> Не выходит со сна

Ядро. Баг-репорт на [bugzilla.kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/).
И если Вы ещё не в курсе, можно ставить более свежие ядра из [Kernel-ppa/mainline](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) и тестировать с ними "входы и выходы".

> просто зависает, падает окружение рабочего стола!

Нужно обращать внимание на сообщения о том, что именно, какой компонент упал. Если же никаких сообщений.... ...логи читать умеем (dmesg, syslog, Xorg.0.log)?

Исходя из указанных моделей лептопов, там у обоих интегрированное Intel HD. Если обнаружено, что падения происходят по вине видео-драйвера, можно попробовать задействовать режим modesetting, создав файл /etc/X11/xorg.conf со следующим содержимым (после - перегрузиться):

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel HD"
    Driver "modesetting"
EndSection
```

---

> а если поставить скачивать обновление вовремя установки

а это как?

Еще правильно было бы проверить состояние HDD. Например при помощи gsmartcontrol.

P.S. Также я бы предложил использовать файловую систему Btrfs, которая позволяет делать снимки и в любой нужный момент откатиться на любой из созданных ранее.

> Возможно не у меня одного проблемы такие с Ubuntu 16.04.01 ?

Возможно. Беспроблемного ПО не существует в принципе. И чаще всего проблемы с ПО дополняются проблемами от ума.

> Стоит ли вернутся к Ubuntu 14.04 ? Или вообще поменять ОС

Не стоит. Тут просто поверьте.